# URL parameters not passing to form in Adobe Experience Manager

Tags: javascript, adobe, aem

I have the following code that I am using on a platform called FormAssembly and it works flawlessly with the provided URL for the form.

However, when I post the full HTML for this code into AEM the code no longer passes the variables to the form. It still writes to the console without any issue, it just won't pass to the form.

How the form gets put on AEM is the following:

1. I pull the full HTML from FormAssembly.
2. The full HTML is then pasted into AEM.

Unfortunately I don't have access to AEM, but for some reason have been tasked to solve this.

[image]

```html
<script type="text/javascript">


//Used to pull URL
  
const link = window.location.href;
const url = new URL(link);


//Function to get the URL parameters
function getParameterByName(name) {
  return url.searchParams.get(name);
}

//Gathering the URL Parameters and writing to console to check if parse is accurate -- Note the console.log can be removed if needed
var period = getParameterByName('period');
console.log(period);

var loan = getParameterByName('loan');
console.log(loan);

var ltv = getParameterByName('ltv');
console.log(ltv);

var transaction = getParameterByName('transaction');
console.log(transaction);

var property_type = getParameterByName('property_type');
console.log(property_type);

var fico = getParameterByName('fico');
console.log(fico);

var occupancy = getParameterByName('occupancy');
console.log(occupancy);

var cashout = getParameterByName('cashout');
console.log(cashout);

var rate = getParameterByName('rate');
console.log(rate);

var fees = getParameterByName('fees');
console.log(fees);

var points = getParameterByName('points');
console.log(points);

var trackingID = getParameterByName('trackingID');
console.log(trackingID);




//On load function to prefill the forms hidden fields
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById("tfa_49").value = period;
  document.getElementById("tfa_50").value = loan;
  document.getElementById("tfa_51").value = ltv;
  document.getElementById("tfa_53").value = transaction;
  document.getElementById("tfa_54").value = property_type;
  document.getElementById("tfa_55").value = fico;
  document.getElementById("tfa_56").value = occupancy;
  document.getElementById("tfa_57").value = cashout;
  document.getElementById("tfa_58").value = rate;
  document.getElementById("tfa_59").value = fees;
  document.getElementById("tfa_60").value = points;
  document.getElementById("tfa_61").value = trackingID;
}


</script>
```

Adding Form HTML:

```html
<!-- FORM: BODY SECTION -->
<div class="wFormContainer" >
    <div class="wFormHeader"></div>
    <style type="text/css"></style><div class=""><div class="wForm" id="55-WRPR" dir="ltr">
<div class="codesection" id="code-55">
  
  
<script type="text/javascript">


//Used to pull URL
  
const link = window.location.href;
const url = new URL(link);


//Function to get the URL parameters
function getParameterByName(name) {
  return url.searchParams.get(name);
}

//Gathering the URL Parameters and writing to console to check if parse is accurate -- Note the console.log can be removed if needed
var period = getParameterByName('period');
console.log(period);

var loan = getParameterByName('loan');
console.log(loan);

var ltv = getParameterByName('ltv');
console.log(ltv);

var transaction = getParameterByName('transaction');
console.log(transaction);

var property_type = getParameterByName('property_type');
console.log(property_type);

var fico = getParameterByName('fico');
console.log(fico);

var occupancy = getParameterByName('occupancy');
console.log(occupancy);

var cashout = getParameterByName('cashout');
console.log(cashout);

var rate = getParameterByName('rate');
console.log(rate);

var fees = getParameterByName('fees');
console.log(fees);

var points = getParameterByName('points');
console.log(points);

var trackingID = getParameterByName('trackingID');
console.log(trackingID);




//On load function to prefill the forms hidden fields
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById("tfa_49").value = period;
  document.getElementById("tfa_50").value = loan;
  document.getElementById("tfa_51").value = ltv;
  document.getElementById("tfa_53").value = transaction;
  document.getElementById("tfa_54").value = property_type;
  document.getElementById("tfa_55").value = fico;
  document.getElementById("tfa_56").value = occupancy;
  document.getElementById("tfa_57").value = cashout;
  document.getElementById("tfa_58").value = rate;
  document.getElementById("tfa_59").value = fees;
  document.getElementById("tfa_60").value = points;
  document.getElementById("tfa_61").value = trackingID;
}

</script>
  


  


</div>
<h3 class="wFormTitle" id="55-T">Mortgage Informa</h3>
<form method="post" action="https://firstfinancialbank.tfaforms.net/responses/processor" class="hintsBelow labelsAbove" id="55" role="form">
<div class="oneField field-container-D    " id="tfa_2-D">
<label id="tfa_2-L" class="label preField reqMark" for="tfa_2"><b>First Name</b></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><input type="text" id="tfa_2" name="tfa_2" value="" aria-required="true" title="First Name" class="validate-custom ^[a-zA-Z]+$ required"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
                        if(typeof wFORMS != 'undefined') {
                            if(wFORMS.behaviors.validation) {
                                wFORMS.behaviors.validation.rules['customtfa_2'] =  { selector: '*[id="tfa_2"]', check: 'validateCustom'};
                                wFORMS.behaviors.validation.messages['customtfa_2'] = "Please enter only letters";
                            }
                        }</script>
</div>
<div class="oneField field-container-D    " id="tfa_3-D">
<label id="tfa_3-L" class="label preField reqMark" for="tfa_3"><b>Last Name</b></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><input type="text" id="tfa_3" name="tfa_3" value="" aria-required="true" title="Last Name" class="validate-custom ^[a-zA-Z]+$ required"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
                        if(typeof wFORMS != 'undefined') {
                            if(wFORMS.behaviors.validation) {
                                wFORMS.behaviors.validation.rules['customtfa_3'] =  { selector: '*[id="tfa_3"]', check: 'validateCustom'};
                                wFORMS.behaviors.validation.messages['customtfa_3'] = "Please enter letters only";
                            }
                        }</script>
</div>
<div class="oneField field-container-D    " id="tfa_1-D">
<label id="tfa_1-L" class="label preField reqMark" for="tfa_1"><b>Email</b></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><input type="text" id="tfa_1" name="tfa_1" value="" aria-required="true" title="Email" class="validate-email required"></div>
</div>
<div class="oneField field-container-D    " id="tfa_4-D">
<label id="tfa_4-L" class="label preField reqMark" for="tfa_4"><b>Phone Number</b></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><input type="text" id="tfa_4" name="tfa_4" value="" aria-required="true" autoformat="###-###-####" title="Phone Number" class="validate-custom /^[1-9]{3}[-][0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{4}$/ required"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
                        if(typeof wFORMS != 'undefined') {
                            if(wFORMS.behaviors.validation) {
                                wFORMS.behaviors.validation.rules['customtfa_4'] =  { selector: '*[id="tfa_4"]', check: 'validateCustom'};
                                wFORMS.behaviors.validation.messages['customtfa_4'] = "Please enter a valid phone number.";
                            }
                        }</script>
</div>
<div class="oneField field-container-D    " id="tfa_5-D">
<label id="tfa_5-L" class="label preField reqMark" for="tfa_5"><b>State</b></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><select id="tfa_5" name="tfa_5" title="State" aria-required="true" class="required"><option value="">Please select...</option>
<option value="tfa_6" id="tfa_6" data-conditionals="#tfa_11" class="">IL</option>
<option value="tfa_7" id="tfa_7" data-conditionals="#tfa_15" class="">OH</option>
<option value="tfa_8" id="tfa_8" data-conditionals="#tfa_28" class="">IN</option>
<option value="tfa_9" id="tfa_9" data-conditionals="#tfa_45" class="">KY</option>
<option value="tfa_10" id="tfa_10" class="">Other</option></select></div>
</div>
<div class="oneField field-container-D    " id="tfa_11-D">
<label id="tfa_11-L" class="label preField " for="tfa_11"><b>City</b></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><select id="tfa_11" name="tfa_11" data-condition="`#tfa_6`" title="City" class=""><option value="">Please select...</option>
<option value="tfa_12" id="tfa_12" class="">Kankakee, IL</option>
<option value="tfa_13" id="tfa_13" class="">Watseka, IL</option>
<option value="tfa_14" id="tfa_14" class="">Hoopeston, IL</option></select></div>
</div>
<div class="oneField field-container-D    " id="tfa_15-D">
<label id="tfa_15-L" class="label preField " for="tfa_15"><b>City</b></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><select id="tfa_15" name="tfa_15" data-condition="`#tfa_7`" title="City" class=""><option value="">Please select...</option>
<option value="tfa_16" id="tfa_16" class="">Columbus, OH</option>
<option value="tfa_17" id="tfa_17" class="">Celina, OH</option>
<option value="tfa_18" id="tfa_18" class="">Cincinnati, OH</option>
<option value="tfa_19" id="tfa_19" class="">Dayton, OH</option>
<option value="tfa_20" id="tfa_20" class="">Hamilton, OH</option>
<option value="tfa_21" id="tfa_21" class="">Harrison, OH</option>
<option value="tfa_22" id="tfa_22" class="">Van Wert, OH</option>
<option value="tfa_23" id="tfa_23" class="">Worthington, OH</option>
<option value="tfa_24" id="tfa_24" class="">Mason, OH</option>
<option value="tfa_25" id="tfa_25" class="">West Chester, OH</option>
<option value="tfa_26" id="tfa_26" class="">Trenton, OH</option>
<option value="tfa_27" id="tfa_27" class="">Upper Arlington, OH</option></select></div>
</div>
<div class="oneField field-container-D    " id="tfa_28-D">
<label id="tfa_28-L" class="label preField " for="tfa_28"><b>City</b></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><select id="tfa_28" name="tfa_28" data-condition="`#tfa_8`" title="City" class=""><option value="">Please select...</option>
<option value="tfa_29" id="tfa_29" class="">Indianapolis, IN</option>
<option value="tfa_30" id="tfa_30" class="">Bloomington, IN</option>
<option value="tfa_31" id="tfa_31" class="">Columbus, IN</option>
<option value="tfa_32" id="tfa_32" class="">Lafayette, IN</option>
<option value="tfa_33" id="tfa_33" class="">Greensburg, IN</option>
<option value="tfa_34" id="tfa_34" class="">Highland, IN</option>
<option value="tfa_35" id="tfa_35" class="">Hartford City, IN</option>
<option value="tfa_36" id="tfa_36" class="">Rochester, IN</option>
<option value="tfa_37" id="tfa_37" class="">Madison, IN</option>
<option value="tfa_38" id="tfa_38" class="">New Albany, IN</option>
<option value="tfa_39" id="tfa_39" class="">Lawrenceburg, IN</option>
<option value="tfa_40" id="tfa_40" class="">Batesville, IN</option>
<option value="tfa_41" id="tfa_41" class="">Shelbyville, IN</option>
<option value="tfa_42" id="tfa_42" class="">Seymour, IN</option>
<option value="tfa_43" id="tfa_43" class="">Richmond, IN</option>
<option value="tfa_44" id="tfa_44" class="">Rushville, IN</option></select></div>
</div>
<div class="oneField field-container-D    " id="tfa_45-D">
<label id="tfa_45-L" class="label preField " for="tfa_45"><b>City</b></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><select id="tfa_45" name="tfa_45" data-condition="`#tfa_9`" title="City" class=""><option value="">Please select...</option>
<option value="tfa_46" id="tfa_46" class="">Louisville, KY</option>
<option value="tfa_47" id="tfa_47" class="">Hebron, KY</option>
<option value="tfa_48" id="tfa_48" class="">Lawrenceburg, KY</option></select></div>
</div>
<div class="oneField field-container-D     wf-acl-hidden" id="tfa_49-D">
<label id="tfa_49-L" class="label preField " for="tfa_49"><b>Period</b></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><input type="text" id="tfa_49" name="tfa_49" value="" title="Period" class=""></div>
</div>
<div class="oneField field-container-D     wf-acl-hidden" id="tfa_50-D">
<label id="tfa_50-L" class="label preField " for="tfa_50"><b>Amount</b></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><input type="text" id="tfa_50" name="tfa_50" value="" title="Amount" class=""></div>
</div>
<div class="oneField field-container-D     wf-acl-hidden" id="tfa_51-D">
<label id="tfa_51-L" class="label preField " for="tfa_51"><b>LTV</b></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><input type="text" id="tfa_51" name="tfa_51" value="" title="LTV" class=""></div>
</div>
<div class="oneField field-container-D     wf-acl-hidden" id="tfa_52-D">
<label id="tfa_52-L" class="label preField " for="tfa_52"><b>Source</b></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><input type="text" id="tfa_52" name="tfa_52" value="" title="Source" class=""></div>
</div>
<div class="oneField field-container-D     wf-acl-hidden" id="tfa_53-D">
<label id="tfa_53-L" class="label preField " for="tfa_53"><b>Transaction</b></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><input type="text" id="tfa_53" name="tfa_53" value="" title="Transaction" class=""></div>
</div>
<div class="oneField field-container-D     wf-acl-hidden" id="tfa_54-D">
<label id="tfa_54-L" class="label preField " for="tfa_54"><b>Property Type</b></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><input type="text" id="tfa_54" name="tfa_54" value="" title="Property Type" class=""></div>
</div>
<div class="oneField field-container-D     wf-acl-hidden" id="tfa_55-D">
<label id="tfa_55-L" class="label preField " for="tfa_55"><b>FICO</b></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><input type="text" id="tfa_55" name="tfa_55" value="" title="FICO" class=""></div>
</div>
<div class="oneField field-container-D     wf-acl-hidden" id="tfa_56-D">
<label id="tfa_56-L" class="label preField " for="tfa_56"><b>Occupancy</b></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><input type="text" id="tfa_56" name="tfa_56" value="" title="Occupancy" class=""></div>
</div>
<div class="oneField field-container-D     wf-acl-hidden" id="tfa_57-D">
<label id="tfa_57-L" class="label preField " for="tfa_57"><b>Cashout</b></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><input type="text" id="tfa_57" name="tfa_57" value="" title="Cashout" class=""></div>
</div>
<div class="oneField field-container-D     wf-acl-hidden" id="tfa_58-D">
<label id="tfa_58-L" class="label preField " for="tfa_58"><b>Rate</b></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><input type="text" id="tfa_58" name="tfa_58" value="" title="Rate" class=""></div>
</div>
<div class="oneField field-container-D     wf-acl-hidden" id="tfa_59-D">
<label id="tfa_59-L" class="label preField " for="tfa_59"><b>Fees</b></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><input type="text" id="tfa_59" name="tfa_59" value="" title="Fees" class=""></div>
</div>
<div class="oneField field-container-D     wf-acl-hidden" id="tfa_60-D">
<label id="tfa_60-L" class="label preField " for="tfa_60"><b>Points</b></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><input type="text" id="tfa_60" name="tfa_60" value="" title="Points" class=""></div>
</div>
<div class="oneField field-container-D     wf-acl-hidden" id="tfa_61-D">
<label id="tfa_61-L" class="label preField " for="tfa_61"><b>Informa Tracking ID</b></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><input type="text" id="tfa_61" name="tfa_61" value="" title="Informa Tracking ID" class=""></div>
</div>
<div class="actions" id="55-A"><input type="submit" data-label="Submit" class="primaryAction" id="submit_button" value="Submit"></div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<input type="hidden" value="55" name="tfa_dbFormId" id="tfa_dbFormId"><input type="hidden" value="" name="tfa_dbResponseId" id="tfa_dbResponseId"><input type="hidden" value="0474c1303e390b268a35393d6f761c3e" name="tfa_dbControl" id="tfa_dbControl"><input type="hidden" value="86" name="tfa_dbVersionId" id="tfa_dbVersionId"><input type="hidden" value="" name="tfa_switchedoff" id="tfa_switchedoff">
</form>
```

Comment: Well, your code seems to look fine. How are we able to check if it works? What is AEM? Are all the parameters in the URL whenever you visit the form?

Comment: Hello,  AEM is Adobe Experience Manager. It allows users to build websites like Wix or Squarespace. All of the parameters are in the URL when I visit both URLS. They even write to the console. I added a snippet of the console.

Comment: What happens when you log on of the inputs and it's value in the `onload` callback?`console.log(document.getElementById("tfa_49"));` or `console.log(document.getElementById("tfa_49").value));`.

Comment: It shows the desired value when I test on my end. I will pass that along to the team that uses AEM to test. Unfortunately I don't have access to AEM. So testing will need to be done by that team.

Comment: Can you add the HTML markup of the form?

Comment: @EdLucas I added it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tl:Dr
Changed window.onload to $( document ).ready

I had to change from:

```js
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById("tfa_49").value = period;
  document.getElementById("tfa_50").value = loan;
  document.getElementById("tfa_51").value = ltv;
  document.getElementById("tfa_53").value = transaction;
  document.getElementById("tfa_54").value = property_type;
  document.getElementById("tfa_55").value = fico;
  document.getElementById("tfa_56").value = occupancy;
  document.getElementById("tfa_57").value = cashout;
  document.getElementById("tfa_58").value = rate;
  document.getElementById("tfa_59").value = fees;
  document.getElementById("tfa_60").value = points;
  document.getElementById("tfa_61").value = trackingID;
}
```

to:

```js
//On load function to prefill the forms hidden fields
$( document ).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById("tfa_49").value = period;
  document.getElementById("tfa_50").value = loan;
  document.getElementById("tfa_51").value = ltv;
  document.getElementById("tfa_53").value = transaction;
  document.getElementById("tfa_54").value = property_type;
  document.getElementById("tfa_55").value = fico;
  document.getElementById("tfa_56").value = occupancy;
  document.getElementById("tfa_57").value = cashout;
  document.getElementById("tfa_58").value = rate;
  document.getElementById("tfa_59").value = fees;
  document.getElementById("tfa_60").value = points;
  document.getElementById("tfa_61").value = trackingID;
});
```